Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise assessment risk score always returns zero
I added Google reCAPTCHA enterprise key and appropriate service account.
I listed two domains in enterprise key configuration (Also tried to disable domain verification at all).
I am getting logical assessmentResponse.getRiskAnalysis().getScore() = 0.9 assessments one one domain and but always getting zeros on another domain. I use same configuration on both servers. Both domains are verified in google search console, as well as admin console.
Do you have any idea what can be the reason or how can I troubleshoot this issue?
I didn't manage to make assessments work on both domains.

Referencing this public issue tracker with the same concern as yours, there are many reasons why the scores are: 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9 and as well as 0.0 which is an expected score. reCaptcha enterprise learns by monitoring real traffic on your site, and looking on those scores, those values are subject to change in the future, look at them as thresholds and not check absolute values. Therefore, scores in a staging environment and within 7 days of implementation might differ from the long-term production scores.
You can check these reference documents as well for more details on creating assessments for websites and latest version of Google Cloud recaptcha Enterprise
